# Passing Values from a factory to controller angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This may look like a silly question, but it almost take an entire 3 hours, but still couldn't figure out what I have done wrong here. Possibly some one can point out the reason and how to fix this issue (I feel this is a easy fix, but still couldn't see it). So here's the matter, I have [this](http://nhnent.github.io/tui.image-editor/latest/index.html) `javascript` library integrated to `angularJS` application. I used a angular `factory` to provide this service to where it needs, so I can bind this to a single button click event, and initiate the functionalities of the integrated library. Now I need to take some values as parameters from the `controller` this factory function uses and pass those values from the `factory` to `controller` which is the controller that responsible for initiate the third party library. here's what I have so far.

[This is a git repository with the same error](https://github.com/sanirasimato/AngularJSTUIImageEditor)

[image]

**imageEditor factory**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('appEdit').factory('imageEditorService', [
        '$mdDialog',imageEditorService
    ]);

    function imageEditorService($mdDialog) {
        return {

            showImageEditorDialog: function (_width,_height) {

                return $mdDialog.show({
                    controller: 'imageEditorCtrl',
                    templateUrl: './imageEditor.html',
                    clickOutsideToClose: true,
                    locals: {
                        initialData: null,
                        width: _width,
                        height: _height
                    }
                });
            },
        };
    }
})();
```

**imageEditor Controller**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module("appEdit").controller("imageEditorCtrl" , ['width','height',imageEditorCtrl]);


    function imageEditorCtrl(width,height) {
        //this outputs the width, height passed to this properly
        console.log(width+','+height);

        setTimeout(
            () => {

                var imageEditor = new tui.ImageEditor('#tui-image-editor-container', {
                    includeUI: {
                        loadImage: {
                            path: './images/imageEditor/test.png',
                            name: 'SampleImage'
                        },
                        theme: blackTheme,
                        initMenu: 'crop',
                        menuBarPosition: 'bottom'
                    },
                    cssMaxWidth: 700,
                    cssMaxHeight: 300
                });

                // this is where I need the width, height should be bound
                imageEditor.setCropRect(width,height);

                window.onresize = function () {
                    imageEditor.ui.resizeEditor();
                }

            }
            , 1000)
    };

})();
```

**mainController**

```
(function(){
"use strict";

angular.module('appEdit')
    .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope','imageEditorService', function ($scope, imageEditorService) {

        $scope.openImageEditorDialog = function (width, height) {
            imageEditorService.showImageEditorDialog(width, height);
    };
    }]);
 })();
```

**HTML where I used this mainCtrl**

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <md-button ng-click="openImageEditorDialog(400,200)">Open</md-button>
</div>
```

**The Error**

> angular.js:14110 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: widthProvider <- width <- imageEditorCtrl
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.9/$injector/unpr?p0=widthProvider%20%3C-%20width%20%3C-%20imageEditorCtrl
>       at http://localhost:1337/vendor/angular/angular.js:68:12
>       at http://localhost:1337/vendor/angular/angular.js:4554:19
>       at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:1337/vendor/angular/angular.js:4707:32)
>       at http://localhost:1337/vendor/angular/angular.js:4559:45
>       at getService (http://localhost:1337/vendor/angular/angular.js:4707:32)
>       at injectionArgs (http://localhost:1337/vendor/angular/angular.js:4732:58)
>       at Object.invoke (http://localhost:1337/vendor/angular/angular.js:4754:18)
>       at $controllerInit (http://localhost:1337/vendor/angular/angular.js:10518:34)
>       at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:1337/vendor/angular/angular.js:9416:34)
>       at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:1337/vendor/angular/angular.js:8757:13) undefined

I know this error occurs with a typo kind of issues, but here I can not understand why this occurs.
**with `console.log(width+','+height)` I could confirm the width and height is set properly and it comes to the controller, but the problem is with the provided error, entire functionality of the third party library is breaks down(it won't initiate at all). without the width, height parameters it works just fine**

Comment: Where should these values come from? From the URL? From inputs in the view?

Comment: @RenatoLucasChitolina I just updated the question, for better understand. Hop you can understand the problem than before now.

Comment: Which version of angularJS you are using?

Comment: Where are you getting width and height for this line `imageEditor.setCropRect(width,height);`

Comment: @GangadharJannu it's angular v-1.7.5
and `function imageEditorCtrl(width,height)` this is where it comes.

Comment: Now this makes sense. Remove width, height params for your controller

Comment: @GangadharJannu I know it will solve the problem, But what if I need to pass those values from the `factory` to `controller` ?

Comment: @Sanira Can you check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52702649/3543808)  let me know if it works?

Comment: You're using v1.7.5? Then why url in error points to v1.5.9? I can't see `angular` (without suffix) in your `package.json` nor in `bower.json`. Are you sure that both pure angularjs and addons are v1.7.5?

Comment: @barbsan It's a big project from my company and a pretty old one. So there can be some conflicts, but I personally implement this code with angular v1.7.4. It has nothing but the files regarding to this matter. so it gives me the same error. I'll update the question with that error message.

Comment: @barbsan It's a big project from my company and a pretty old one. So there can be some conflicts, but I personally implement this code with angular v1.7.4. It has nothing but the files regarding to this matter. so it gives me the same error. I'll put that error here

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: widthProvider <- width <- editorUICtrl
https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.4/$injector/unpr?p0=widthProvider%20%3C-%20width%20%3C-%20editorUICtrl
    at angular.js:138
    at angular.js:4905
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:5065)
    at angular.js:4910
    at getService (angular.js:5065)
    at injectionArgs (angular.js:5090)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:5114)
    at $controllerInit (angular.js:11673)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:10486)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:9801)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I sort it out, I did a really really stupid thing, and as I was suspecting It was just an easy fix. I just bind the `controller` again to the `templateHTML`, and that causes the problem. it's just confuse the build flow with the same `controller` which binds to a `HTML Element` twice. So just removing the controller bind from the `templateHTML` file, just fix the problem.

**previous templateURL file**

```
<div ng-controller="imageEditorCtrl"> <!--this line which causes the problem with controller bind-->
    <div style="width:80vw; height: 500px">
        <div id="tui-image-editor-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**fixed version**

```
<div>
    <div style="width:80vw; height: 500px">
        <div id="tui-image-editor-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the issue is with Dependency Injection.

Change your imageEditor Controller definition as below

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module("appEdit").controller("imageEditorCtrl", [imageEditorCtrl]);

    function imageEditorCtrl($scope, $mdDialog, initialData, width, height) {
        this.$onInit = function () {
            var imageEditor = new tui.ImageEditor('#tui-image-editor-container', {
                includeUI: {
                    loadImage: {
                        path: './images/imageEditor/test.png',
                        name: 'SampleImage'
                    },
                    theme: blackTheme,
                    initMenu: 'crop',
                    menuBarPosition: 'bottom'
                },
                cssMaxWidth: 700,
                cssMaxHeight: 300
            });

            // this is where I need the width, height should be bound
            imageEditor.setCropRect(width, height);

            window.onresize = function () {
                imageEditor.ui.resizeEditor();
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: Already try those bro, still no luck. no errors with `$scope` or `$mdDialog`, it's just the `width` and `height` gives the error. I'll try to add a `plunker` or `fiddle` regarding this.

Comment: That would really help us in debug the issue

Comment: I have linked a git repo with the same error, You can refer to that.

Comment: still not working?. Have you tried my updated answer?

Comment: I tried the updated one mate, still no luck. width and height undefined then. I suspect it happens with `setTimeout`

Comment: Would be great if you could provide a fiddle or jsbin so that we can debug. We can see the code from GitHub but we can't debug that

Comment: mate I tried everything, but couldn't reproduce the error or make it work with any of the online code editor. If you could clone my repository and run it with a server(apache, etc) you'll be able to see the error with my code. I am working with a big project, So the solution for this issue is the key for everything. Still no luck with any changes I've being trying.

Comment: The error clearly shows that `width` is an unknown provider. I'm still confused why the below  code is not working `angular.module("appEdit").controller("imageEditorCtrl" , [imageEditorCtrl])`

Comment: You have to remote `width` and `height` in array. Have you done that?

Comment: "You have to remote `width` and `height` in array." what do you mean by that?

Comment: Just replace your imageEditorCtrl definition with the one I have suggested in my comment

Comment: Ya, then `TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null` error occurs, to overcome that I have to put the code snippet inside the `setTimeout()` then the same error occurs. **And with this one `width` and `height` become undefined**

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code, but the main thing you need to get down is Dependency Injection(DI) in angularJS:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

You created your service, imageEditorService, but you need to inject it in your controller:

```
angular.module("appEdit").controller("imageEditorCtrl" , ['imageEditorService',imageEditorCtrl]);


function imageEditorCtrl(imageEditorService) {
```

You cannot inject 'height' and 'width' into your controller, as they are not 'providers', as your error suggests. To use the service in your controller, call:

```
imageEditorService.showImageEditorDialog(height, width); // Specify the height and width.
```

That said, I am not sure what you want to do in your controller. Do you want to instantiate a new tui.ImageEditor, or do you want to use your imageEditorService?

If you want to use tui.ImageEditor, use your factory/service to do that.

Some tips: Make sure you understand the difference between controllers and services/factories/providers. Also, get familiar with the controller lifecycle, such as the build-in init hook:

[What is the lifecycle of an AngularJS Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094940/what-is-the-lifecycle-of-an-angularjs-controller).

Comment: Seems like you didn't understand the question properly. I used this factory to just initiate the image editor. so it makes it ease to inject into any controller and using it I can instantiate the image editor where ever I need. BTW I know the difference between a controller/service/factory and a provider. This way I can pass the values to the controller, **which is the controller bound to the factory, but when I use this method to pass the values, the image editor instantiation disrupted some how**.  
How ever I can see the question doesn't seems clear, I'll update the question.